# Hibernate inheritance mapping with ManyToOne relationships for child class

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-onetomany

Having a mapping with Employee Class to Task Class as a OneToMany mapping.
*(Employee having a List of Task objects.)*

Employee class extends Person class.

Class Diagram as below,

[image: Here is the class diagram]

I tried it as ***Table per concrete class methodology *** with the following code, but it didn't worked

Person.java

```
@Entity  
@Table(name = "Person ")  
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)  
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private int age;

    // implemented getters and setters
}
```

Employee.java

```
@Entity  
@Table(name="Employee")  
@AttributeOverrides({  
    @AttributeOverride(name="id", column=@Column(name="id"))
})  
public class Employee extends Person{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String jobName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Task> tasks;

    // implemented getters and setters
}
```

Task.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Task")
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String taskName;

    private double deadLine;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "employeeID")
    private Employee employee;

    // implemented getters and setters
}
```

How to do the hibernate mapping for this,

Comment: What is the issue you are having?

Comment: Its shows ID is not with the define. Mapping exception

Comment: Do you have the stacktrace?

Comment: The whole point was to extend Person right? Employee didn't even extend Person?

Comment: Sorry my fault, I corrected it now. Thanx.